# GParted Maximum /boot Partition Size?

Tags: boot, partitioning, arch-linux, gparted, dualboot

I have an Arch dual boot system with Windows on my desktop PC (not a laptop). It's been while since I've last messed around with it and now I would like to "revive" it. One of the first things I went on to do was a global system update (`pacman -Syu`). But then I received this error:

```
error: Partition /boot too full: 4916 blocks needed, 3320 blocks free
```

So I checked my `/boot` partition and it turns out it only had 100MB, with 96MB being used already. I then tried to find out how I could increase its size and some posts recommended the classic GParted for it. I felt uneasy, as this is very delicate stuff, but, since I couldn't find other options, I decided to give it a go.

I then unallocated 1GB from my Arch partition, moved it two or three times upwards until it was near the `/boot` partition and finally merged the two. I cringed when GParted showed me this — sorry for the image quality, I had to downgrade it to upload it here —:

[image: GParted Error]

Strangely, both Windows and Arch recognize the new `/boot`'s size as 1.1GB, despite the error. This is what I get from Arch when trying to update it again:

[image: Arch Error]

Why is this happening? Is there a solution? Is it because GParted cannot resize the `/boot` partition beyond a certain size? Is this documented somewhere?

(Everything in my system seems to be working just fine though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because GParted cannot resize the /boot partition beyond a certain size? Is this documented somewhere?

libparted cannot resize FAT16/FAT32 partitions to certain sizes.

There is some code within libparted related to conversion between FAT16 and FAT32 – smaller partitions need to use FAT16, larger ones (2 GB and above) need to be converted to FAT32, and apparently there is a certain range *in between* where libparted just gets completely confused and its calculation code accepts neither FAT16 *nor* FAT32 for the requested size.

Nobody seems to have touched this code in the last 10 years since it was re-added.

> Strangely, both Windows and Arch recognize the new /boot's size as 1.1GB, despite the error.

The *partition* that contains /boot has been resized to 1.1 GB, but the *filesystem* has not. The FAT filesystem structure that's in nvme0n1p2 is still "managing" only the same 100 MB of space as before – its file allocation table hasn't been increased to handle the newly available sectors, etc.

> Is there a solution?

Back up all files from the partition, reformat it with `mkfs.fat`, copy the files back into it.

Comment: "Back up all files from the partition, reformat it with `mkfs.fat`, copy the files back into it." Could please be more specific about the steps here? Do you have a link to a more detailed post?

Comment: What is the proper way of backing up the files of this type of partition? How do I reformat it to `mkfs.fat`? How do I copy file into this type of partition afterwards?

Comment: Should I separate the last part of the answer into another question?

Comment: I've continued the overall problem [here](https://superuser.com/q/1717850/1066947).