# How to properly expand /boot FAT partition (for Arch Linux)

Tags: partitioning, arch-linux, gparted, fat32, boot-partition

> This post is actually a continuation of [this GParted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1717415/1066947).

I was trying to update/upgrade my Arch dual-boot with Windows, but my `/boot` partition was too small (100MB). So I expanded it with 1GB via GParted. Unfortunately for me, this is not the proper way of expanding a `/boot` partition.

[@user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686) mentioned a solution though. However, I don't know how to properly execute any of the steps. Could anyone offer me more details?

Here are his instructions:

1. Back up all files from the partition

   - How do I properly back files from a `/boot` partition?
2. Reformat the `/boot` partition with `mkfs.fat`

   - How do I reformat it in this way? Can GParted do it?
3. Copy files back into the `/boot` partition

   - How?

I wonder, though, if it isn't easier to simply use something like [ArchLinux GUI](https://archlinuxgui.in/) install and hope it does a better job with the `/boot` partition.

By the way, I don't even know why the `/boot` partition was so small in my last install, this is the second time I install Arch in a dual-boot fashion — due to one of my Corsair RAM memories trashing my whole hardware —, and I don't remember having this problem back then.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I properly back files from a `/boot` partition?

There's nothing special in the [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) (which is what at the `/boot` mount point by default), it's just a normal FAT partition like any other FAT data partitions. UEFI knows about file systems so fixing boot issues is very easy, no need to mess up with the boot sectors. Just do a normal copy like `cp -r /boot /mnt/backup_folder` or use the GUI in file explorer

But that requires you to mount the partition somehow. In this case the partition has been resized but the file system hasn't been resized yet, so I guess you can still mount it in Linux. If that's true then the above command is good to go. When restoring the files back in step 3 do the same copy in reverse direction

If you can't mount `/boot` then try copying just the exact old filesystem area to file and mount it as a loop device

```sh
sudo dd if=/dev/esp of=boot_partition.bin bs=1M count=100 # Copy the 100MiB partition
sudo mount -o loop boot_partition.bin /mnt/boot_backup
```

Then after it's mounted do `cp -r /mnt/boot_backup /mnt/backup_folder`

If the partition can't be mounted then don't worry, the boot files are available on all Linux and Windows installation disks. After creating the ESP, just plug the Windows/Linux installer medium in and copy them from `/EFI` into the new `/boot` partition for the step 3

Notice the folder structure in `/EFI` for those disks, but also don't worry too much, if the directory tree is wrong just open the EFI shell and select the correct boot loader you want to boot

---

> How do I reformat it in this way? Can GParted do it?

I don't know if gparted can do it or not. As you already have the backed up data, just give it a try. If it fails then use `mkfs.fat`. You can check the [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/mkfs.fat.8) for more information. The command would be like this

```
mkfs.fat -F 32 -s 1 -S 4096 /dev/your_boot_partition
```

You just need to care about the `-S LOGICAL-SECTOR-SIZE` and `-s SECTORS-PER-CLUSTER` options. You need to check your logical sector size by running `fdisk -l`. It's probably 4096 bytes for an NVMe, and in that case to get 4096-byte cluster use `-s 1`. If the device uses 512-byte sector then use `-s 8 -S 512`

Comment: Do you know why the EFI space happened to be so small? I don't remember if it was automatically done by Windows, which I installed first.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro [Windows creates a 100MB ESP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions?view=windows-11) on [512-byte-sector disks](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/esp-size-guide.html) because there's no reason to make it large. Arch Linux is one of the rare cases where a large ESP is required because it stores kernels directly in the ESP by default. You can tell it not to do that way